# Use TOTP to prevent simulating requests

Tags: passwords, http, hmac

I'm developing an API system which provides functionalities for a game. Currently, we are using HMAC to prevent simulating requests (let's say, prevent hackers from simulating the game) but because we encountered some issues with HMAC, I thought that it could be better to use a temporary password. Same as what Google Authenticator does.

I'd like to know is this a good approach to use TOTP to generate a temporary password from client and send it to the server via HTTP request and validate it on the server? The goal is to prevent simulating or sending requests from 3rd-party clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) **is** an HMAC.  It just happens to be an HMAC of a timestamp with some granularity where the passwords need to be rotated.  Note that with either a time-based HMAC or some other HMAC, an attacker with a copy of a legitimate client can extract the shared key and use that key to forge requests from their client.